# SQL - Get the count of each distinct value with condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have three tables

```
 **room**
    room_id | nurse_needed
    ----------------------
    1       | 3
    2       | 1
    3       | 2


**doctor_schedule**
    doctor_schedule_id| room_id | date     |shift
    -------------------------------------------------
           1          | 1       |12-30-2016|   1
           2          | 2       |12-31-2016|   2
           3          | 3       |12-30-2016|   2
           4          | 2       |12-30-2016|   2
*nurse_schedule*
    nurse_schedule_id | doctor_schedule_id
    --------------------------------------
    1                 |         1         
    2                 |         1         
    3                 |         3
```

Each shift in room have one doctor and in each shift need a number of nurse.Nurses work with doctor's schedule. I want to count how many shift don't have enough nurse in `12-30-2016`. The result should be:

```
    doctor_schedule_id| room_id | date     |shift | nurse_needed|nurse_have_in_room
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           1          | 1       |12-30-2016|   1  |     3       |    2
           3          | 3       |12-30-2016|   2  |     2       |    1
           4          | 2       |12-30-2016|   2  |     1       |    0
```

Comment: why is doctor_schedule_id 4 not in the result?

Comment: because it has roon_id =2 which need 1 nurse, in (nurse_schedule_id = 4) has (doctor_schedule_id =4)

Comment: where is `nurse_have_in_room` supposed to come from?

Comment: How many shifts are in a day?

Comment: @CharlesBretana In table nurse_schedule, I map nurse_schedule with doctor_schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `INNER JOIN` all the table like this and filter away the ones where required number of nurses is less than or equal to number of them already present.

```
select d.doctor_schedule_id,
    d.room_id,
    d.date,
    d.shift,
    r.nurse_needed,
    COUNT(distinct n.nurse_schedule_id) nurse_have_in_room
from doctor_schedule d
inner join room r on r.room_id = d.room_id
left outer join nurse_schedule n on d.doctor_schedule_id = n.doctor_schedule_id
where d.date = '12-30-2016'
group by d.doctor_schedule_id,
    d.room_id,
    d.date,
    d.shift,
    r.nurse_needed
having r.nurse_needed > COUNT(distinct n.nurse_schedule_id);
```

Comment: `HAVING SUM(r.nurse_needed) > COUNT(n.nurse_schedule_id)` - that seems to be wrong. It should be `HAVING r.nurse_needed > COUNT(n.nurse_schedule_id)`.

Comment: I query it and the result show that the `nurse_needed` in  room is wrong

Comment: @tuanptit I've just tested it on my system and it gave me the exact same result as you expected. Are you sure you ran the query from most updated answer? Can you try once more?

Comment: I am sorry that i did not check carefully. But I only want to count in `12-30-2016`. In that day has 2 shift don't have enough nurse is shift 1 and shift 2. Please update your answer.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh But when `doctor_schedule_id =4` don't have any `nurse_schedule`, your query don't show the record have `nurse_have_in_room = 0`. Please see my updated question

Comment: @tuanptit It's just a change of INNER JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN. I've updated my answer and it give the expected result

Answer (score 1):

You could join `doctor_schedule` with `room` and an aggregate query on `nurse_schedule`:

```
SELECT d.*, r.nurse_needed, n.nurses_in_room
FROM   doctor_schedule d
JOIN   room r ON d.room_id = r.room_id
JOIN   (SELECT   doctor_schedule_id, COUNT(*) AS nurses_in_room
        FROM     nurse_schedule
        GROUP BY doctor_schedule_id) n ON 
       d.doctor_schedule_id = n.doctor_schedule_id AND
       r.nurse_needed > n.nurses_in_room
```

Comment: I only want to count in 12-30-2016. In that day has 2 shift don't have enough nurse is shift 1 and shift 2.